# Need some help with the fabricate spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm having trouble mathing my way to success with the Fabricate spell.  Say I want to magic a pile of adamantine into an Earth Breaker.  Would I be able to do that in one cast of fabricate?  How much adamantine is in one cubic foot, and how much would that translate for weapon that weighs 14lbs?

Math was not my strong suit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know the volume of the material you can [*fabricate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate) (up to 1 cu. ft./level for a mineral) into something, and you also know the weight of an Earth Breaker (14 lb.), what you'd need is a density.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=steel%20density) tells me that the density of steel is 7.88 g/cm³, which is around 490 lb./ft.³. Note that the density of steel is sufficient to know because the *volume* (i.e. the size) of the final product doesn't change when you change the material. Nevertheless we can also assume this to be the density of [adamantine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Adamantine), since the rules don't state any differences in weight for either weapons or armor made from it.

Multiply 490 by the volume you can manipulate and you end up with the total weight of steel objects you can create with the spell, i.e. 490lb./level for a mineral. If your character happens to own a huge pile of adamantine<sup>*</sup>, he can thus create 35 Earth Breakers per caster level with a single casting of the spell, provided he makes the required crafting checks.

<sup>* Incidentally, the price of such a huge pile of adamantine is based on what you turn it into.</sup>

Comment: Great answer! I suspected that was the case based on my research but it seemed so simple!